# Geocalization android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm designing an app with a MapsActivity that will update my location, but when I run it I only get the world map without telling me my position. I do not see the fault, I have tried many things .

```
 package com.example.dani.etakemongo.ProductionFrontends;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dani.etakemongo.DevelopFrontends.Menu;
import com.example.dani.etakemongo.Modelo.Usuario;
import com.example.dani.etakemongo.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

String tag = "MapsActivity";
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker marcador;
double lat = 0.0;
double ing = 0.0;
String email2, emailaMenu;
int idusuario, idusuarioaMenu;


FloatingActionButton menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    Log.d(tag, "Event onCreate()");


    email2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
    emailaMenu = email2;


    //BOTON MENU
    menu = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_menu);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                goToMenu(v);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String error = ex.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });



    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    miUbicacion();

}

//Metodo para incluir un marker, CameraUpdate para centrar la camara a la posicion del marker
private void agregarMarcador(double lat, double ing) {

    LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, ing);
    CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);
    if (marcador != null)
        marcador.remove(); //Si el marcador diferente de null le añadimos propiedades, titulo, imagen
    marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coordenadas)
            .title("Mi posicion")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)));
    mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
}

//Metodo para obtener latitud y longitud de nuestra posicion actual
private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {  //Comrpobamos la localizacion recibida es diferente de null antes de asignar valores a las valariables
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        ing = location.getLongitude();
        agregarMarcador(lat, ing);
    }
}

//Implementamos un objeto del tipo LocationListener, su funcion es estar atento a cambio de localidad recividio por el GPS
LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualizarUbicacion(location);//Llamamos anuestro metodo para actualizar la ubicacion
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};

//Metodo para obtener servicio de posicionamiento, nos da la ultima posicion obtenida y se actualiza cada 15 segundos

private void miUbicacion() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    actualizarUbicacion(location);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10000,0,locListener);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onStart()");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onResume()");

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onPause()");

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onStop()");

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onRestart()");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(tag, "Event onDestroy()");

}


public void goToMenu(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("email2",emailaMenu);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 800);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you on 6.0+? If so, you will need to dynamically request location permissions, as mentioned in the comment block in `miUbicacion`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in onMapReady

```
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    miUbicacion();
    if (PermissionUtils.checkPermission(HomeActivity_.this, 
                  PermissionConstant.LOCATION_PERMISSION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }

}
```